# Rosetta Stone v5.0 on OS X and failed activation with "Error 8111"

Tags: macos, locale, localization, i18n, rosetta-stone

I've purchased a downloadable version of Rosetta Stone (Spanish) v5.0 recently. It can be installed on two computers simultaneously.

My Mrs. and I got the same copy of the installer, installed it and tried to activate the software. I managed to activate it within a second, but I kept getting a weird error code 8111 on my wife's laptop running the same OS X 10.10.3 as mine.

After spending a couple of hours with Rosetta's support telling me to follow [the instruction](http://support.rosettastone.com/en/language-learning/articles/Error-8111-while-activating-Rosetta-Stone-Version-4-TOTALe/#Mac) I had already tried an hour ago, I was close to give up and ask for a refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, I was hit by the idea that the only difference was our system language settings. I was running OS X with an English locale, but my wife had Russian enabled.

I switched her system language to English and Rosetta Stone was activated like a charm.

Most probably there's a major and mature bug preventing product activations with non-Eglish locales of OS X. I hope my findings will save some time for someone else.

Comment: Good find. I hope you reported it to the developers as well, because that bug really needs to be fixed.